# Is there a command to restart the Xcode iOS simulator from command line?

Tags: xcode, command-line, ios-simulator, xcrun, simctl

I have found a command to killall simulators but does not fit my needs. I need to be able to restart a particular simulator given the udid.

I have tried shutdown and then boot the simulator using

```
$ xcrun simctl shutdown <udid>
$ xcrun simctl boot <udid>
$ open -a simulator
```

but the simulator hangs after the execution of these commands.

Xcode version: 10.3
Simulator version: iPhone XS iOS: 12.4

Comment: Can you update your question with Xcode version and iOS simulator version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using xcode 11.3 but this seems to work for me:

```
export UDID=$(xcrun simctl list devices | grep "(Booted)" | grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})")  
xcrun simctl shutdown $UDID
xcrun simctl boot $UDID
```

Might be worth giving it an update to the latest xcode.

Comment: Just updated to Xcode 11.1 and it works. Thanks alexrogers!